# Android Multiple Web service Call in Single AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How to call multiple web services call from single Asynctask,Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Are they synchronous? Then call the first, the second...

```
public class WSTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,AccountsOverview_LABean>{


    @Override
    public void onPreExecute(){
        // show progress dialog or something if you want.
    }  

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Object> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            ArrayList<Object> a=new ArrayList<Object>();
            a.add(WebService1()); // WebService1 returns the data that you want
            a.add(WebService2()); // WebService1 returns the data that you want
            a.add(WebService2()); // WebService1 returns the data that you want

            return a
            d.cancel();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Object> param){
        // stop loading icon or loading dialog...

        // Manage the content of the arrayList like you need.

    } 

} //WSTask
```

Comment: It is all the code. Save all returned data into diferent positions of the arrayList. In the onPostExecute method, the parameter 'param' is the arrayList that you have been created in 'doInBackground'.